# accordion button within <h2> fails to open or close

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

The accordion was working fine until I moved the `<h2>` tag outside of the button as it was failing html5 validation.

I do not know too much of javascript and found the code on the w3schools website. it works just fine when the `<h2>` tag is inside the `<button>` tag.

#### HTML:

```
<h2><button class="accordion" id="uses">Lorem ipsum</button></h2>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="accordioncontent">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum...</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      }
    }
</script>
```

#### CSS:

```
h2 button.accordion {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 43px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}


button.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795';
    font-size: 25px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2716";
}

div.panel {
    width: 880px;
    max-height: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.accordioncontent {
    padding: 18px 25px;
    min-height: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due this line:
`this.nextElementSibling;`

While the `h2` is inside the button, the sibling of the element button is the div with class .panel. Once you put the button inside a `h2` the `nextElementSibling` it doesn't find a sibling because it's the only child inside the element.

You should imagine all this like a tree

```
Document
+-H2
| +-Button
+-div.panel
```

Check the info about the DOM tree https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp and the info about how is working the nextElementSibling https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_nextelementsibling.asp property of an element

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        console.dir(this);
        <!--No siblings for button inside h2 element-->
        console.dir(this.nextElementSibling);
        <!--Existing sibling for parent Node-->
        var panel = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      }
    }
```

```css
h2 button.accordion {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 43px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}


button.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795';
    font-size: 25px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2716";
}

div.panel {
    width: 880px;
    max-height: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.accordioncontent {
    padding: 18px 25px;
    min-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<h2><button class="accordion" id="uses">Lorem ipsum</button></h2>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="accordioncontent">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum...</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: beautifully explained... this was spot on... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS, you are using h2 tag.

```
h2 button.accordion {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 43px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: left; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this js line:

```
var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
```

for this:

```
var panel = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
```

Becouse the **nextElementSibling** function try get the next html object after button. If you have h2 tag inside button tag then the next tag is div tag with panel class but if you moved Button inside h2 tag then Button is the last object and the **nextElementSibling** function returns nothing.

Call the **parentNode** function before **nextElementSibling** function will return the next object after parent of button. In this case parent of button tag is h2 tag and next object after h2 tag is the div tag with panel class.